# All-set-homogeneous spaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, topological-groups, isometries, isometry-groups

This is a follow-up to the question of Joseph O'Rourke [Which metric spaces have this superposition property?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/118008/)

A metric space $X$ will be called all-set-homogeneous if for any subset $A\subset X$ any distance-preserving map $A\to X$ can be extended to an isometry $X\to X$.

*Classical examples* include Euclidean spaces, Lobachevsky spaces, and spheres (all with canonical metrics and up to rescaling).

> Is it true that complete all-set-homogeneous *length*-metric spaces include only the classical examples *plus* the so-called [universal $\mathbb{R}$-trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9904133) of finite valence?

We have a partial answer, which requires the following definition.

Given a metric space $X$, consider all pseudometrics induced on $n$ points $x_1,\dots, x_n\in X$.
Such a metric is completely described by $n{\cdot}(n-1)/2$ real numbers $|x_i-x_j|_X$, so it can be encoded by a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n{\cdot}(n-1)/2}$.
The set $F_n(M)\subset \mathbb{R}^{n{\cdot}(n-1)/2}$ of all these points is called the $n^\text{th}$ fingerprint of $X$.

We know that all-set-homogeneous *length*-metric spaces with closed fingerprints include only the basic examples.
(We do not assume local compactness.)
The proof is very short, you may check it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09671), but likely it is not new.

> Is it new?

**Remarks**

- Locally compact all-set-homogeneous length spaces include only basic examples; in fact, in this case, 3-point-homogeneity is sufficient. It follows from the result of J. Tits ["Sur certaines classes d'espaces homogènes de groupes de Lie" (1955)];
- It seems that condition that the space is length can not be seriously connected to all-set-homogeneity. So we expect that there are counterexamples to the first question.
- It was shown by Birkhoff that all-set-homogeneous geodesic space with local uniqueness of geodesics has to be classical [See his *Metric foundations of geometry. I*].

Comment: Are you able to prove that a complete all-set-homogeneous length space that is not an $\mathbb{R}$-tree is one of the basic examples?

Comment: @JamesHanson, no --- actually, I will add completeness to the problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use your Ramsey theory argument with the Erdős–Rado theorem to show that any all-set-homogeneous metric space (with no extra conditions) must have cardinality at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. I don't know how directly applicable it is to your problem, but this is pretty similar to techniques used in model theory to extract indiscernible sequences.

Comment: Also in my subfield of model theory in particular, we sometimes consider conditions similar to finite-set-homogeneity (from your note), but for us we find an approximate version of the condition more tractable. In your context, it would be something like this: For any finite set $A$, distance-preserving $f: A \to M$, and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an isometry $g: M \to M$ such that for each $a \in A$, $d(f(a),g(a)) < \varepsilon$. Might be interesting to consider.

Comment: @JamesHanson could you give a ref with the approximate condition?

Comment: The relevant property shows up in Corollary 12.11 in [Model Theory for Metric Structures](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~henson/cfo/mtfms.pdf), where it's called *$\omega$-near-homogeneity*. In my thesis, I refer to it as *approximate $\omega$-homogeneity* or *approximate $\aleph_0$-homogeneity*. I can't remember if I saw my version of the term somewhere else.

Comment: A model theorist would probably refer to your property as *ultrahomogeneity* though, since it only concerns quantifier-free types (i.e., the specification of the pairwise distances between points). Also, (the completion of) what you're calling the $n$th fingerprint would be called the space of quantifier-free $n$-types by a model theorist.

Comment: Also, if you do end up digging into this literature, I should note that 'officially' continuous logicians (i.e., those who do model theory of metric structures) only study things with bounded metrics, but it's know that there are ways around this.

Comment: I just remembered that the most directly relevant paper is probably [this paper of Ben Yaacov's on Fraïssé limits of metric structures](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43864204).

Comment: @JamesHanson Thank you so much --- all this is new for me. If you could make an answer from you comments I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an observation and a long comment than an answer.

The observation is that a fairly standard application of the Erdős–Rado theorem implies that in any metric space with more than $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ many elements, there is an infinite sequence $(a_i)_{i<\omega}$ of distinct elements satisfying $d(a_i,a_j) = d(a_0,a_1)$ for any $i<j<\omega$. By the argument in your note this is enough to imply that any all-set-homogeneous metric space (with no assumption of completeness or length-ness) has cardinality at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

The comment regards connections between your question and concepts that have been studied in model theory, particularly in [the model theory of metric structures](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehenson/cfo/mtfms.pdf).

In your note, you mention a variation of this question in which you only require homogeneity over finite sets. In discrete structures, this kind of homogeneity is studied in model theory and is referred to as *ultrahomogeneity* (as opposed to ordinary homogeneity, which requires a stronger relationship between the two finite sets of elements to get an automorphism). The relevant concept here is that of a [*Fraïssé class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_limit), which is a class of finite structures satisfying the properties of the class of finite substructures of an ultrahomogeneous structure. Fraïssé's theorem is the statement that it is possible to construct the structure itself from the class in a particular way. In particular, countable ultrahomogeneous structures (in a finite relational language) are precisely characterized as the Fraïssé limits of Fraïssé classes (although this doesn't necessarily help that much with actually characterizing such structures precisely).

In my subfield of model theory, known as *continuous logic*, we apply model-theoretic techniques to structures with underlying metrics, such as metric spaces, Banach spaces, $\mathbb{R}$-trees, and so on. [Fraïssé limits have been studied in the context of continuous logic by Ben Yaacov](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43864204), although frankly the necessary formalism is quite technical when compared to the discrete version. As is often the case in continuous logic, some of the defining properties of Fraïssé classes need to be modified to only hold in some approximate sense. Here the natural notion is that of approximate ultrahomogeneity. In particular, a metric space $X$ is *approximately ultrahomogeneous* if for any finite $A \subseteq X$, any distance-preserving map $f : A \to X$, and any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an isometry $g : X \to X$ such that $d(f(a),g(a)) < \varepsilon$ for every $a \in A$.

So, using Ben Yaacov's machinery, I am able to give a technical and possibly useless answer to a modification of a question you did not ask here, which is that the separable approximately ultrahomogeneous metric spaces are precisely the limits of Fraïssé classes (in the sense of Ben Yaacov) of finite metric spaces.

Unfortunately, the all-set-homogeneity property doesn't have analogs that have been studied by model theorists to my knowledge. The issue is that, as we already saw, properties of this sort tend to limit the size of the structure involved, and this makes it a little awkward to use model-theoretic tools.

Finally, I can comment on the axiomatizability of the class of length spaces in continuous logic. A fairly well-known fact is that complete length spaces can be characterized as those complete metric spaces that admit approximate midpoints (i.e., for any $a,b \in X$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $c \in X$ such that $d(a,c)$ and $d(c,b)$ are both within $\varepsilon$ of $\frac{1}{2}d(a,b)$. This condition can be easily expressed in continuous logic by the closed condition $\sup_{xy}\inf_{z} \max(|d(x,z)-\frac{1}{2}d(x,y)|,|d(z,y)-\frac{1}{2}d(x,y)|) = 0$, so for any $r > 0$, the class of (complete) length spaces of diameter at most $r$ is elementary (in the sense of continuous logic, which by default only deals with complete metric structures). Dealing with unbounded metric spaces, while doable in continuous logic, is a bit trickier. It can be accomplished using Ben Yaacov's [extension of continuous logic to unbounded metric structures](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219061308000737). In this situation too, it is possible to axiomatize the class of length spaces, but it's a little bit more complicated to state how precisely.

Comment: A metric $d$ can be made bounded by passing to $\phi\circ d$ for a concave continuous bijection $\phi\colon[0,\infty)\to [0,1)$. Further, one may redefine length metric using $\phi$. So the condition that space is bounded does not look essential --- it seems to be there just by technical reasons. Am I right?

Comment: Another question: I see that length spaces can be described in continuous logic, but were they considered in the theory?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin The problem with bounding the metric like that is that model theorists usually think about all models of a given theory. If you shrink the metric down like that, there's no way to avoid having points of distance $1$ in the new metric. This may or may not be okay, but it means that if you represent, say, $\mathbb{R}$-trees in this way, you actually get '$\mathbb{R}$-forests.'

Comment: @AntonPetrunin To my knowledge there is no published work on general length spaces in the context of continuous logic. The fact that they're axiomatizable might be folklore but I personally noticed it when I looked through various properties studied in metric geometry to see whether they could be formalized in continuous logic.